# OpenCV camera intrinsics matrix to Ogre projection matrix for Augmented reality

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, augmented-reality, ogre

I've written a simple Augmented Reality application using *Ogre* + *OpenCV*. All is working, but I need to match Ogre's virtual camera to my real camera

I don't know camera parameters (it's a cheap webcam and vendor is not providing them). I'm able to get camera intrinsic with `cvCalibrateCamera2` (after some `cvFindChessboardCorners` as described [here](http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/~noahKuntz/openCVTut10.html)) and I save them with `cvSave`.

```
cvCalibrateCamera2(objectPoints_, imagePoints_, pointCounts_,
        imageSize, cameraMatrix, distortionCoeffs_, NULL,
        NULL, CV_CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO );
cvSave(INTRINSIC_XML, intrinsicMatrix_);
```

AR application loads the intrinsic matrix:

```
CvMat* intrinsic = (CvMat*) cvLoad(INTRINSIC_XML);
```

So `intrinsic->data.db` is a pointer to a 9 length array of double (3x3 matrix)
How can I translate this to a `Ogre::Matrix4` such I can use it with `setCustomProjectionMatrix`.

I've found something in [Ogre's Forum](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=22584&p=214518#p214518) but this is not working. I guess some other step is needed between the 3x3 matrix found by OpenCV and the 4x4 matrix needed by `Ogre::Camera`.

I hope there's some way of doing this with intrinsics given by `cvCalibrateCamera2`. If none, I'll need to take a ruler and a protractor and get parameters (roughly) by hand.

This is the 3x3 "intrinsics" matrix:

```
836.391     0.000   460.430 
  0.000   836.391   281.440
  0.000     0.000     1.000
```

Comment: Can u type the actual values of the camera matrix?

Comment: @SumeetJindal I've edited question, adding intrinsics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the projection matrix as follows.

mat[0,0] = fx

mat[1,1] = fy

mat[2,2] = +- .01

mat[3,2] = +- 1

mat[3,3] = 0

where 
fx = intrinsic [0] / imageSize.Width;

fy = intrinsic [1*3 + 1] / imageSize.Height;

Try combinations of negative and positive values for mat[2,2] and mat[3,2].

Typically both will have negative values.
Other parameters can be ignored

Comment: Please, can you explain this? mat[2,2] is related to near/far clip distance?

Comment: Yes Z = mat[3,2] * ZObject + mat[3,3]. near = (0 - mat[3,3])/mat[3,2]

Comment: far = (1 - mat[3,3])/mat[3,2]

Comment: Nearplane is the Z at which ZProjected becomes 0 and far plane at which it becomes 1

Comment: I'm trying to get this working, but something is still unclear to me. Look at http://pastebin.com/ChNtpSuJ if it good. Reading log, I guess after using `setCustomProjectionMatrix` you cannot get camera updated parameters like `camera->getFOVy()` because they remain the same as before `setCustomProjectionMatrix`. It looks enough similar to reality, but I need to deepen. Can you suggest some documentation on how this matrix works? Where camera will be placed after doing this? At 0,0,0?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb147302%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Multiply the 3rd matrix in this link by D you will get my matrix

Comment: You need to set all other matrix elements to zero. No need to do getProjectionMatrix. Try rendering some object at origin first.